# How to create linux/unix group based permission in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql, mapr

we have many databases with tables in it in hive and we want to give access to user according to Linux/Unix group, currently we are using hive role and user level permission but we want to switch to linux/unix group for table and database level permission. How can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't controlled at the Hive level. You'd just `hadoop fs -chmod` the directories where the data is

By default, Hadoop access is not authenticated or secured; username checks are based purely on strings, not really Unix group names. In other words, clients can easily bypass your checks.

In order to do this properly, you need an LDAP and Kerberos server for authorization and authentication. With an LDAP server, you can use `sssd` to create local users and groups across your cluster, but to properly authorize them, you should issue keytabs rather than rely on Unix permission sets.

To further secure the system, Apache Ranger can be used to restrict, obfuscate, and audit data access

Comment: we don't have apache ranger or apache sentry at our cluster and also admin team don't support them.

Comment: we want to assign hive roles to Linux group, currently hive roles are assigned to user id, is there any solution to do that in hive?

Comment: Like I said, it's controlled at the HDFS level, with chmod commands, not Hive.